# How to set a form validator to true based on conditions?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-forms, form-control

I need to make a validator in a form to true if a certain conditions satisfies. My code is given below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.joinee = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('joinee'));
    this.Id = this.joinee.JoineeID;
    this.isPersonalDocumentsVerified = this.joinee.isPersonalDocumentsVerified;
    this.personalDocForm = this.fb.group({
      photograph: ['', Validators.required],
      resume: ['', Validators.required],
      aadhaar: [''],
      panCard: [''],
      passport: [''],
      drivingLicense: [''],
      votersId: ['']
    });

    
    this.uploadService.getData(this.Id).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.uploads = result;


        if (this.uploads[0].photographUrl !== null) {
          
         //make the validators of photograph in personalDocForm to true here
          
        }
        

      },
      error => {
        
        throw error;
      }
    );
  }
```

I need to set the validation for Photograph field to true if the data is there from backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are setting up photograph as required in the form definition so in order to satisfy that condition then you need to set the photograph control to some value, which presumably is the url. You can use this.personalDocForm.patchValue({ photograph: this.uploads[0].photographUrl })

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo in this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3stbvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

YOu need to `setValue()` of photograph control in subscribe() method.

```
turnTrue(){
   this.photo.patchValue(true, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
}
get photo(){
  return this.formData.controls['photo'];
}
```

Below is template html code you can fire validation when photo is true..

```
{{formData.value | json}}
 <div *ngIf="photo.value === true">
     Photo is Empty
 </div>
 <button (click)="turnTrue()">Photo to True </button>
```

Comment: the following error comes in console

DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: @RobyA Check update answer. Now Error has gone. just pass option to `patchValue(true, {emitModelToViewChange: false}`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to set photograph url to `photograph` control when it has photographUrl

```
if (this.uploads[0].photographUrl !== null) {
   this.personalDocForm.get('photograph').setValue(this.uploads[0].photographUrl)
}
```

Comment: Actually photograph in the form accepts only Files (IForm Files to backend) ...Url is a different thing for this